# for loop to sum data group and arrange it then break and print the value while ignore NA

Tags: r

How can i use for loop to sum data by group then break and print the value accumulated sum of A and B respectively?
ie:

```
Type value
A  2
A  NA
A  13  15
B  565
B  245
B  578  1388
```

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(cs = cumsum(value, na.rm = True))
```

but it only shows the whole table and originally should be sum A should be 15 but eventually become NA.

```
Type value cs
A     2    2
A     NA   NA
A     13   NA
B     565  565
B     245  810
B     578  1388
```

Comment: Hi DD3, can you try to be a little more precise? I am not sure what you mean by "but it only shows the whole table and originally should be sum A should be 15 but eventually become NA.". Also, if you provide a reprex, it will improve your chances of quickly getting a more concrete answer. (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Also, please include the package you are using for your pipes, consider including more tags, it will make your question more visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you can try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>%
    mutate(cs = last(sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
      mutate(id = row_number()) %>% # Creating a dummy id column
        mutate(cs= replace(cs, id!= max(id),NA)) %>% # replace all rows of cs that are not the last within group Type
          select(-id) # removing id column
#Output
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Type [2]
  Type  value    cs
  <chr> <int> <int>
1 A         2    NA
2 A        NA    NA
3 A        13    15
4 B       565    NA
5 B       245    NA
6 B       578  1388
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the OP expects that all rows of the new column `cs` are *blank* except for the last row of each group where the sum of the values belonging to the group should be printed.

A *blank row* is only possible if the new column `cs` is of type *character*. In case `cs` is expected to be of *numeric* type then there is no other choice to print either `0`, `NA`, or any other numeric value, but not `""` (empty string).

So, below there are suggestions to create a character column either by using

- `ifelse()`, or
- `replace()` and `rep()`, or
- `c()` and `rep()`.

in `data.table` and `dplyr` syntax, resp.

Note that *no* `for` loop is required at all.

#### `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, cs := fifelse(1:.N == .N, as.character(sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)), ""), by = Type][]
```

or

```
setDT(df)[, cs := replace(rep("", .N), .N, sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Type][]
```

or

```
setDT(df)[, cs := c(rep("", .N - 1L), sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)), by = Type][]
```

> ```
>    Type value   cs
> 1:    A     2     
> 2:    A    NA     
> 3:    A    13   15
> 4:    B   565     
> 5:    B   245     
> 6:    B   578 1388
> ```

#### dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(cs = ifelse(row_number() == n()), sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), ""))
```

or

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(cs = replace(rep("", n()), n(), sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

or

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Type) %>% 
  mutate(cs = c(rep("", n() - 1L), sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 6 x 3
> # Groups:   Type [2]
>   Type  value cs    
>   <chr> <int> <chr> 
> 1 A         2 ""    
> 2 A        NA ""    
> 3 A        13 "15"  
> 4 B       565 ""    
> 5 B       245 ""    
> 6 B       578 "1388"
> ```